# What does "virtual headset plug inserted" of Android emulator mean?

Tags: android-emulator

[The official document](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator) says:

```
The Android Emulator doesn't include virtual hardware for the following:

Bluetooth
NFC
SD card insert/eject
Device-attached headphones
USB
```

However, the emulator has the following settings:
[image]

Could anyone shed some light on what these settings mean?
The following code returns false for the emulator:

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE)
```

Comment: What a shame, that nobody is willing to answer this. I'm stuck while answering the question, if the microphone input will work in current android emulator versions, and came past this entry too. Old answers were clear about the inability to use the microphone, and the https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder page even states, that it cannot record audio after all. But then, there is a virtual headset that even seems to have a microphone. So what now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a way to make Android think I have connected headphones but enabling  `Virtual headset plug inserted` is not enough. Do do that you have to install **Lesser AudioSwitch** and [set input device to headset](https://ivanderevianko.com/2021/02/fix-smule-headphones-are-required-to-save-your-collab-on-android-emulator)

Only then `getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE)` will return `true`

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, turning on the "Virtual headset plug inserted" in the emulator will send a broadcast "action=android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG".
Set up a broadcastreceiver for action.HEADSET_PLUG to detect unplug/plug of wired headsets.